# Pyspark: rdd in json object

Tags: python, pyspark

## This is homework assignment

hw2-files-10mb.txt is json data

```
rdd = sc.textFile('./hw2-files-10mb.txt')
rdd = rdd.map(json.loads)

Output of rdd.take(1):

[{'created_at': 'Tue Feb 23 17:42:31 +0000 2016',
  'user': {'id': 470520068,
    'id_str': '470520068',
    'name': 'Marni Halasa',
    'screen_name': 'MarniHalasa1',
    'location': 'NYC',
....]
```

Question:

1) How to select 'id_str' in 'user' in rdd way?

I tried the method to map the rdd to the func which return field_list = ['user.id_str'] but it is not working.

```
field_list = ['user.id_str', 'text']
def f(x):
d = {}
for k in x:
    if k in field_list:
        d[k] = x[k]
return d

rdd1 = rdd.map(f)

Output:
[{'text': "I'm voting 4 #BernieSanders bc he doesn't ride a CAPITALIST PIG adorned w/ #GoldmanSachs $. SYSTEM RIGGED CLASS WAR"}]
```

2) How to remove the tweet where 'created_at' field is not exist?

My codes below is not working. It returns error when i use rdd.count()

```
rdd = rdd.filter(lambda row: row['created_at'] is not None)
```

My expected output:

1) Remove all the broken tweets ('created_at' field is empty)

2) a pair RDD of (user_id, text), where user_id is the 'id_str' data field of the user dictionary.

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Here's how to improve the quality of your post - this will get you better answers, faster.  (1) Provide example data inline, instead of posting partial output from a file.  It doesn't have to be the actual data (although that's best), but something that allows you to generate a [mcve]; (2) Provide expected output.  (For example: what do you want to do with `id_str` once it is selected?  Remember Spark has lazy evaluation); (3) It's not required, but still a good idea, to label this post as homework, when it is (your filename suggests this is a homework assignment).

Comment: Noted. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Solve the 2) point first as after extracting `'user.id_str'` and `'text'`, there will not be the `created_at` field left to filter on.

2) Just check the if `'created_at'` is present. Also, you can do all operations in a single go.

```
rdd = sc.textFile('./hw2-files-10mb.txt')\
            .map(json.loads)\
            .filter(lambda row: 'created_at' in row.keys())
```

1) You don't need a function to extract values from a json object.

```
rdd = rdd.map(lambda row:(row['user']['id_str'], 'text'))
print rdd.take(1)
```

Comment: The correct for this homework 1) rdd = rdd.map(lambda row:(row['user']['id_str'], row['text']))